# excel duplicate values pairs in multiple column

Tags: excel, duplicates

Is there a way to find duplicate pairs in multiple columns in Excel?

For instance,

```
column1       column2  

Smith         Jones       <-- duplicate pair  
Smith         Johnson  
Jones         Smith       <-- duplicate pair  
Jones         Walter
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I would do it would be as follows:
(Assuming your data begins in cell A1 & B1)

- In C1, put in the formula: `=A1&"|"&B1`
- In D1, put in the formula: `=B1&"|"&A1`
- In E1, put in the formula: `=MATCH(C1,$D$1:$D$500,0)`
- Drag all these down for your dataset (and change the `$500` in your final formula if necessary)
- Any place where column E has a number, it means the data is duplicated - You could even filter for anything that isn't `#N/A` and it tells you where in the list the duplicate match is.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Wouldn't your logic say that the pair ("ABC", "DEF") matches ("AB", "CDEF") then...or ("ABC", "DEF") matches ("CDEF", "AB")?

Comment: Yup - You're right, I updated my answer to correct for that... Good catch!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want a single column to indicate duplicates of this type, you can use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((CONCATENATE($A$1:$A$500,"^",$B$1:$B$500)=CONCATENATE(B1,"^",A1))*1)
```

This will give you the number of duplicates of the type you have in your table. You can apply a filter on all the values from there which are non-zero. Just change the range of `$A$1:$A$500` and `$B$1:$B$500` if need be. It will depend on the size of your table.

Or if, by any change you want to use conditional formatting, you can select columns A and B, click on 'Conditional Formatting', 'New Rule', 'Use formula to determine which cells to format', paste in the formula:

`=SUMPRODUCT((CONCATENATE($A$1:$A$500,"^",$B$1:$B$500)=CONCATENATE(B1,"^",A1))*1)>0`

then pick a formatting from the button 'Format...' (I usually go for 'Fill' and pick yellow) which will highlight the duplicates in column B.

Answer (score 1):

I'd first create a column by concatenating the sorted values of Column's 1 and 2 (and a space in the middle).  Then I'd just look for duplicates in that column.  The following should do it:

1. In C1, **=IF(A1<=B1,A1 & " | " & B1,B1 & " | " & A1)**
2. In D1, **=COUNTIF($C$1:$C$999,C1)>1**

Then just copy cells `C1`, and `D1`, all the way down the spreadsheet.  Column D should contain `TRUE` for any duplicate pairs.

**Edit:** Changed delimeter (still not foolproof, but better)

Comment: I would use a different delimiter in the stead of a space. While cases like "John, Doe Smith" and "Smith, John Doe" is rare, it's not impossible and I think it's better to use a character not commonly found in names :)

Comment: @Jerry:  Good call.  I never considered multiple names.  I suppose the "ideal" solution for arbitrary data would be to encode each name somehow, escape a special character, then use that special character as a delimiter.