# Finding Duplicate Pairs in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

So I have this summary sheet. It contains data from multiple workbooks going across.

It's not like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823468/excel-duplicate-values-pairs-in-multiple-column), because what I'm trying to do is find all the inconsistant pairs of data in this worksheet going across and highlight them.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0qvj73ua/) that explains what I want to accomplish. I have a large worksheet, and would like to compare the first 2 rows with the next 2 rows etc. throughout the worksheet. Below is an HTML representation of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
<table class="tg">
<tr>
<th class="tg-031e">#INT1</th>
<th class="tg-031e">#INT1</th>
<th class="tg-031e">#INT2</th>
<th class="tg-031e">#INT2</th>
<th class="tg-031e">#INT3</th>
<th class="tg-031e">#INT3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-031e">Apples</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Y</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Bananas</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Y</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Apples</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Y</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-031e">Bananas</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Y</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Peppers</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Y</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Bananas</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Y</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-031e">Peppers</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Y</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Pomegranite</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Y</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Peppers</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Y</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-031e">Pomegranite</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Y</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Nuts</td>
<td class="tg-031e">YYYYYNN</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Pomegranite</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Y</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-031e">Nuts</td>
<td class="tg-031e">YYYYYYNN</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Smango</td>
<td class="tg-031e">NNNYYNNN</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Nuts</td>
<td class="tg-031e">NNNYNNNN</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-zl7m">Oranges</td>
<td class="tg-zl7m">YYYYNNNN</td> <!-- this oranges is different from... -->
<td class="tg-031e">Blackberries</td>
<td class="tg-031e">NNNYYNNNN</td>
<td class="tg-zl7m">Oranges</td> 
<td class="tg-zl7m">NNNYYNNN</td> <!-- ...this one -->
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-031e">Smango</td>
<td class="tg-031e">NNNYYNNN</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Berries</td>
<td class="tg-031e">YYNYNNNN</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Smango</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Y</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-031e">Skiwi</td>
<td class="tg-031e">NNNYNNNN</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Beer</td>
<td class="tg-031e">NNNYNNNN</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Steaks</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Y</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-031e">Steaks</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Y</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Blueberries</td>
<td class="tg-031e">YNNYNNNN</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Steaksauce</td>
<td class="tg-031e">NNNYNNNN</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-zl7m">Steaksauce</td>
<td class="tg-zl7m">YYNYNNNN</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Blucheese</td>
<td class="tg-031e">NNNYNNNN</td>
<td class="tg-zl7m">Apricot</td>
<td class="tg-zl7m">YYYYNNNN</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-031e">Apricot</td>
<td class="tg-031e">YYYYNNNN</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Blackberries</td>
<td class="tg-031e">NNNYNNNN</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Milkshake</td>
<td class="tg-031e">NNNYNNNN</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have tried VBA solutions and also conditional formatting. Any solution that will make this work is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: Even with the fiddle it is not clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you consider to be an inconsistent pair vs. a "consistent pair".

Comment: I tried searching for duplicates, but that only gives me values on one column, like [right here](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/find-duplicates.html). A consistant pair would consist of, for instance if you look at the fiddle: Bananas is associated with 'Y' three times. Also, 'Nuts' has the same value pair in both E and F as well as A and B. I meant to highlight Oranges and Steaksauce not the apricot part.I have updated the Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/0qvj73ua/1/. You can see how both Oranges and Steaksauce are inconsistent. I am comparing the first 2 values throughout the worksheet.

Comment: Is there anyway I could do some conditional formatting that would just highlight the pairs consistent data? For instance: Bananas Y. Wherever that is true, Bananas and Y will be highlighted. Same with any data pair that is the same. I have been working on this problem for a long time, but nothing I have seen is like what I'm doing. I'm trying to go across. I know there has to be a VBA macro or conditional formatting equation that will do this task, but I have not come across it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this array formula should work:-

```
=SUM(ISODD(COLUMN())*($A$2:$E$12=A2)*($B$2:$F$12<>B2))
```

if the table starts in A1, this can be applied as conditional formatting from A2 to E12 and will highlight the left-hand (fruit) cell of inconsistent pair of cells.

Then you can use a similar formula to highlight the right-hand cell of each pair:-

```
=SUM(ISEVEN(COLUMN())*($A$2:$E$12=A2)*($B$2:$F$12<>B2))
```

Apply this from B2 to F12.

[image]

Note that Smango are highlighted because they are in an inconsistent group (although they are also in a consistent group).

Here is the alternative approach (as suggested) of highlighting the consistent groups:-

[image]

The formulae are

```
=SUM(ISODD(COLUMN())*($A$2:$E$12=A2)*($B$2:$F$12=B2))>1
```

and

```
=SUM(ISEVEN(COLUMN())*($A$2:$E$12=A2)*($B$2:$F$12=B2))>1
```

to be applied as before.

The sum this time will always be at least one because each pair of cells will match with itself, so the '>' sign is to find if there are any matches with other pairs of cells.

Comment: Thank you! The second half worked for me, although I think the highlighting made navigating through excel rather slow, I was able to get what I needed.

Comment: Good! Yes, I suspected the array formula might be a bit slow if applied to a large number of cells.